# PHP XML Parser - ignoring nested/child tags

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I've got a situation where I'm using an XML parser to extract data from a php://input.

The data being sent in looks like:

```
<this>foo</this>
<that>bar></that>
<data><dong>zebras</dong><fong>monkeys</fong></data>
```

Now, the issue is that because the handler:

```
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();

xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, false);
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startTag", "endTag");
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "contents");

$document = file_get_contents("php://input");                  

xml_parse($xml_parser, $document);

xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
```

...is interpreting tags for me to decipher the contents to make it useful... It seems to be missing anything within `<data>` i.e. I need to find out how i can get it to ignore the child/nested elements/tags and just bosh out the data whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WideDonkey, have you considered using the DOM instead? You can easily do :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('data');
$data = $data[0]->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but

```
<?php
function contents($parser, $data) {
  echo $data;
}

$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, false);
// xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startTag", "endTag");
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "contents");
// $document = file_get_contents("php://input");
$document = '<x><this>foo</this><that>bar</that><data><dong>zebras</dong><fong>monkeys</fong></data></x>';
xml_parse($xml_parser, $document);
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
```

prints

```
foobarzebrasmonkeys
```

Comment: Hi Volkerk,

Thanks for the response. What i need it to do it say foobar<dong>zebras</dong<fong>monkeys</fong>

i.e. withinn <data> all contents is printed, almost as source, with tags.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was using SimpleXML to do:-

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($input);

$whatIwant = $xml->bar->monkeys
```

You can go down as many levels as you want such as test

The $xml is the furthest out wrapper tag.

Answer (score 0):

[phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) gives you all the power of jQuery Selectors wrapped up in a PHP shell.

```
phpQuery::newDocumentFileXHTML('my-xhtml.html')->find('p');
```