# PHP Get text between xml entities with xml parser

Tags: php, xml, parsing, saxparser

I have the following xml:

```
<BLOCK>
<T>
  Step-by-step learn guide to building your first
  <em>landing page</em>
  learn hello
</T>
<U></U>
<L></L>
</BLOCK>
```

I am attempting to get everything wrapped in T. I am able to get the first line, stuff wrapped in em, however the last line I am losing.

I am using [SAX parsing](https://www.php.net/xml). Answers telling me to switch parsers are not options.

Comment: Have you tried to add one more blank line then? :D

Comment: If the last line is lost by every xml, then it is a parser bug, and you should report it in a bug report...

Comment: I am getting the XML from google site search, I have no way to know if the text on the 3rd line will span additional lines. There might also be additional em tags. In reality I just want to get back everything wrapped in T since em is an html tag. Not an xml tag I need to parse

Comment: Try it on local xml-s. If it seems like ok, then the xml from google has an error. Download it, and check it. Btw I recommend you to write unit tests for testing your parser...

Comment: So you don't want to parse the inside of the T? Hmm then its content should be in CDATA :S

Comment: Can you give me a link to the XML?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to skip the HTML elements with SAX parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064716/sax-parser-to-skip-some-elements-which-are-not-to-be-parsed
if they are valid xml elements (so if they are not inside a cdata section).

Comment: I have no way to change the XML and put the data in CDATA. Like I said the XML is from google site search API. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en has an example towards the bottom of the page

Comment: Ye I see. I don't think it is possible with SAX parser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839287/php-xml-parser-ignoring-nested-child-tags
What is the problem with other parsers? Are they too slow or eat they too much memory?

Comment: The open source software I am using has already integrated it. I am trying to fix this bug but I really did not want to change the parser. But looks like I might end up doing that. My only other option is remove ALL em tags and then bold the keyword later. But thats proving to be a pain as well since google is using partial word bolding

Comment: I was curious how `simplexml` would deal with it, see: https://eval.in/106685

Comment: I ended up switching to simplexml. But I would still like to know how to do it with the other parser